# A quadruple integral similar to Watson's triple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

> Find $$I=\int_0^1{\int_0^1{\int_0^1{\int_0^1{\frac{\left( 1-x^2y^2z^2t^2 \right) dxdydzdt}{\sqrt{\left( 1-x^2 \right) \left( 1-y^2 \right) \left( 1-z^2 \right) \left( 1-t^2 \right) \left( 1+x^2y^2z^2t^2 \right)}}}}}}.$$

This quadruple integral is similar to [Watson's triple integrals](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WatsonsTripleIntegrals.html). By triangular substitution, we obtain $$I=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{1-\cos ^2\alpha \cos ^2\beta \cos ^2\theta \cos ^2\gamma}{\sqrt{1+\cos ^2\alpha \cos ^2\beta \cos ^2\theta \cos ^2\gamma}}d\alpha d\beta d\theta d\gamma}}}}.$$
Due to $$\frac{1-x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=1-\frac{3x^2}{2}+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{\left( -1 \right) ^n\left( 2n-3 \right) !!}{2^nn!}\left( 4n-1 \right) x^{2n}}$$
and
$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\cos ^{2n}xdx}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\Gamma \left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right)}{2\Gamma \left( n+1 \right)}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2n!}\cdot \frac{\left( 2n-1 \right) !!}{2^n}\sqrt{\pi}=\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\left( 2n-1 \right) !!}{\left( 2n \right) !!},$$
we have $$I=\frac{\pi ^4}{16}+\frac{\pi ^4}{16}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\frac{4n-1}{2n-1}\left[ \frac{\left( 2n-1 \right) !!}{\left( 2n \right) !!} \right] ^5}.$$
Thanks to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B(-1)%5E(n)(4n-1)%2F(2n-1)%5B((2n-1)!!)%2F((2n)!!)%5D%5E(5),n%3D1,%20infinity%20%5D), we get 
\begin{align*}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\left( -1 \right) ^n\frac{4n-1}{2n-1}\left[ \frac{\left( 2n-1 \right) !!}{\left( 2n \right) !!} \right] ^5}=& _5F_4\left( -\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};1,1,1,1;-1 \right) \\&-\frac{1}{8}\,_5F_4\left( \frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2};2,2,2,2;-1 \right) -1,\end{align*}
where $_pF_q(a_1,\ldots,a_p;b_1,\ldots,b_q;z)$ is [generalized hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html).

Comment: What exactly is your question? Would you like us to verify your solution?

Comment: @projectilemotion Yes, of course.